# Retrieve image links using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code for which I would like to extract `data-img` links.

```
<a rel="popover" data-img="https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 
4709/Pictures/1001.jpg" href="lot_details.asp?
l=1&amp;lotid=3357969&amp;pageno=1" class="blacklink2" data-original-
title=""><img border="0" src="https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 
4709/Thumbnails/thumb_1001.jpg" width="70" <="" a=""></a>
```

I am using the following Python code but I can't seem to extract the links:

```
urldes = "https://www.johnpyeauctions.co.uk/lot_list.asp?saleid=4709&siteid=1"

# add header
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'} 
r = requests.get(urldes, headers=headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

mylinks = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    mylinks.append(link['data-image'])

for i in range(len(mylinks)):
    mylinks[i]

mylinks_0 = mylinks[0]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. And the statement `mylinks[i]` doesn't seem to do anything. Also provide the URL you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many links in the web page which are all inside the `<a>` tag. So, if you want only the `<a>` tags that have the image links, you'll need to specify more parameters to the `find_all()` method.

Also, have a look at [List Comprehensions in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.johnpyeauctions.co.uk/lot_list.asp?saleid=4709&siteid=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
image_links = [x['data-img'] for x in soup.find_all('a', rel='popover')]
for link in image_links:
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1001.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1002.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1003.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1004.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1005.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1006.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1007.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1008.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1009.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1010.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1011.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1012.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1013.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1014.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1015.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1016.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1017.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1018.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1019.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1020.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1021.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1022.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1023.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1024.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1025.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1026.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1027.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1028.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1029.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1030.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1031.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1032.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1033.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1034.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1035.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1036.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1037.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1038.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1039.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1040.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1041.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1042.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1043.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1044.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1045.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1046.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1047.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1048.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1049.jpg
https://www.johnpyelots.co.uk/Sales/Sale - 4709/Pictures/1050.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly and thx for the link to the guide but here again i'm trying to do the same with the `<h5>` text that goes with each image and I just can't seem to navigate the tags correctly to isolate the specific element.`<td width="41%" bgcolor="#f9f9f7"><a href="lot_details.asp?l=1&amp;lotid=3357969&amp;pageno=1" class="blacklink2"><h5>GUESS C0001G1 GENTS ROSE GOLD TONE AND BLUE BRUSH POLISHED SMART WATCH WITH VOICE COMMAND.  FITTED WITH A BLUE SMOOTH SILICONE STRAP.BOXED AND PAPERS. RRP £259.00</h5></a></td>` Any suggestions?

Comment: Use this - `<td width="41%"`. It's used only for the texts that you want.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Can you correct please? `image_text = [x['a'] for x in soup.find_all('td', width='41%')]
for link in text_links:
    print(link)`

Comment: So I seem to be able to isolate `h5 = soup.find_all(width='41%')
print(h5)` but then I can't move to `<h5>` Can you help?

Comment: I suggest you go through the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It'll help you solve all your doubts.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been doing. I can now isolate `<h5>` with `soup.find(width='41%').find_all('h5')`

Comment: Then you've solved your question. Just use `.find('h5')` instead of `find_all()` since you want a single `h5` element inside the `td` tag.

Comment: Correct but then I would like to retrieve every single iteration of `<h5>` for example `soup.find(width='41%')
for string in soup.find_all('h5'):
    print(string.get('h5'))` but every iteration returns `none`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166287/discussion-between-keyur-potdar-and-alex-b).